# Iterating over all features in featureclass to intersect them individually with polygon using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, polygon, point, intersection

I've got a point featureclass, and I'm trying to individually intersect each feature with a polygon featureclass to get some information about which polygon each feature is in.  I did one intersect with an entire point featureclass against a polygon featureclass, which was straightforward, but I'm not grasping the model for doing the individual intersections.  First attempt below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 *-*
# Name: IntersectingPolygon.py
# Description: Find intersecting polygon on a feature by feature basis

# Import arcpy and set path to data
import arcpy
import csv
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/dev/FGDBs/test.gdb"
intersecting_polygon_layer = 'pg_lyr'
feature_layer = 'feature_lyr'
test_feature = 'some_feature'

# Make a layer of the polygons
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('polygons', intersecting_polygon_layer)

feature_rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(test_feature)

count_features = 0
for feature_row in feature_rows:
    # This line fails, I think because you can't make a layer this way
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(feature_row, feature_layer)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(intersecting_polygon_layer, 'intersect', feature_row)
    polygon_rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(intersecting_polygon_layer)
    print 'Feature Globalid:',feature_row.getValue('globalid')
    for polygon_row in polygon_rows:
        print '\tPolygon objectid:',polygon_row.getValue('objectid')

    if count_features > 5:
        break
    count_features = count_features + 1
```

Comment: Would you be able to include a picture to illustrate why doing the "entire point featureclass against a polygon featureclass" does not meet your requirements, please?  You can certainly do the individual intersections by using the point geometries in place of the point feature layer but I am not clear why, in this instance, you might be wanting to.

Comment: Say for example that the points are homes and the polygons are districts, and I want to know which district each home is in, not which homes are in districts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this I would use the [Intersect (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000p000000) tool.

The ArcPy code will be:

```
import arcpy
homesFC = <your path to input Homes>
districtsFC = <your path to input Districts>
homesWithDistrictFC = <your path to output>

arcpy.Intersect_analysis ([homesFC, districtsFC], homesWithDistrictFC)
```